# subprocess Получить exit code и записать в лог

Tags: python, subprocess

Через subprocess запускаю команду. Задача - вывести исполняемую команду в лог и получить exit code исполняемой команды. Вывести в лог, я понял как, а вот как получить еще и код возврата и в зависимости от этого выполнить действие не понятно.

Пример кода:

```
rsync = 'rsync /tmp/1 /tmp/2'

command_process = subprocess.Popen(
    rsync,
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
command_output = command_process.communicate()[0]

debbug_rsync = open('debbug_rsync.log', 'a+')
debbug_rsync.write('[ {} ]'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
debbug_rsync.write(rsync + '\n')
debbug_rsync.write(command_output)
debbug_rsync.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
command_process = subprocess.Popen(
    rsync,
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
command_output = command_process.communicate()[0]

exit_code = command_process.returncode
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

Comment: Да это то что нужно! Моя ошибка была, в том, что я не понимал за каким процессом следит returncode. Спасибо!

Comment: @никитамерзликин Отметьте ответ как решение, если он им является.

Comment: @никитамерзликин в вашем случае, ещё можно `shell=True` убрать и передать команду в виде списка параметров, а не строки.